# Sizing elements for mobile web

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am new to mobile web development and I am getting rather confused. There are a few things which I do not understand and am having trouble with. I am not currently worried about responsive design, I just building an independent mobile website.

1) What is the standard width of a mobile webpage? Do you use a percentage value and why?

2) Do you ever define heights for elements when designing for mobile? Or for certain instances do you have to use JQuery?

Example for question 2:

Say you want to have 4 square inline elements (images) displayed in a containing div and they also can take up an unlimited number of rows. Now, you have your containing div width set to 80% (assuming that it is best to use percentages), how can you have 4 divs with bottom and right margin appear square? Do you give them percentage widths, if so how do you do the margins?

I know these questions may seem ambiguous, but I am really lost with this, and I cannot seem to find a good tutorial for developing for mobile web.

Answer (score 0):

I find percentages to be easier, but JQuery has better functionality.  Read up on CSS @media queries and how to use them in CSS based on screen sizes.  Also look at viewport meta tags, they'll help you control the user's ability to zoom the page.  Sometimes you might want to restrict or extend that feature.